# finding the solution to a separable ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, analysis

According to my lecture notes, given
$x'(t)=f(x(t))g(t)$
The solution is to integrate
$\int \frac{x'(t)}{f(x(t))}dt=\int g(t) dt$
Getting to the solution
$$F(x(t))=G(t)+C$$, where F is the antiderivative of 1/f and G of g.
I understood it until this point.
Now we introduce the condition $x(t_0)=x_0$
and suddenly the solution $F(x(t))=G(t)+C$ changes to
$F(x(t))=G(t)-G(t_0)+F(x(t_0))$
Now I don't know what happened with the integration constant.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$F(x(t))=G(t)+C$$
Subbing in $t=t_0$
$$F(x(t_0))=G(t_0)+C \to C=F(x(t_0))-G(t_0)$$
Replacing C with our expression we get:
$$F(x(t))=G(t)+F(x(t_0))-G(t_0)$$
It is simply a matter of determining the constant C, given an initial condition we know how a function should behave at a certain point. We can use this information to obtain a value for C.

Answer (score 1):

Since $x(t_0)=x_0$, we want to **choose** $C$ such that $$F(x_0)=G(t_0)+C.$$
Solving for $C$, $$C=F(x_0)-G(t_0).$$
Thus
$$F(x(t))=G(t)+F(x_0)-G(t_0).$$